# questions about /accounts/openid/callback/ and ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I use django-allauth, and I only allow google openid to login.

I try to make it create accounts with the username taken from openid, so I made ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED being True.
It works, but I am not sure whether it is defined in this way.

And, whenever I make the first login(it does not have the account for the openid yet), it always redirect to /accounts/openid/callback.
There is a error in the page with exception value 10061
I don't know what it wants to do and how to fix it.

If the account is existed, it redirects to /accounts/profile and works well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the question:

- You would like to have the "username taken from openid"? The OpenID is an URL -- it's not something to use as `User.username`. Currently, the `User.username` field is autopopulated from either a username explicitly passed by a provider, with a fallback to the a username derived from the e-mail address. See: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/helpers.py#L51
- "error page / 1006" -- this does not ring a bell. Could you please show me the full URL and stack trace?

Comment: I want to get user's profile by openid, and create an account by the username or mail address from the profile. Should I use "ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True"?

Comment: The stacktrace shows that the app is attempting to send a confirmation e-mail via SMTP, though it somehow fails to open a connection to the SMTP server. Do you have a local SMTP server running? If not, please setup EMAIL_HOST (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host) properly...

Comment: I saw the code you post again. I think if I used auto signup, it would have to do the email confirmation. So I turn off the auto signup.
Thanks for your help.